# how to remove E sign from big float number in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

In case of big float numbers , you found in asp .net big float number is showed like this : 
2000000 * 2000000 = 4E+12

How can I show 4E+12 as 4,000,000,000,000 not 4E+12 in server side ?

Comment: please post relevant code...

Comment: Why do you have show a number server-side?

Comment: if 2 numbers 11111111 * 2222 are multiplied the result should be 24688888642 but the result comes as 2.468889E+10.

Comment: as i have to perform some calculation in sever side

Comment: @user1749062, float is irespective of the format, you can perform calculation whether it appears to hold `24688888642` or `2.468889E+10` as both are same

Comment: But according to my requirement the number should display as 24688888642

Answer (score 0):

```
float numb = 4e12f;
string formattedNumber = numb.ToString("N0");
```

Result would be: `formattedNumber = "4,000,000,000,000"`

Comment: can try this for upto 3 digits string formattedNumber = numb.ToString("N0").tofixed(3);

Comment: @user1749062, to restrict formatted string to two decimal places you can try:  `numb.ToString("n2")`. But remeber formatting is only for displaying purpose

Comment: how to restrict the value to 9 digits in client side